# Updating Attribute through reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering if it's possible to reference an object's attribute.

The object User have attribute `first_name`, so normally if we want to update the first name attribute we do:

```
user0 = User.new()
user0.update_attribute(:first_name, "joe")
```

now my question is can I update the `:first_name` attribute through another variable/symbol like so:

```
user0.update_attribute(:fname_ref, "jack")
user0.first_name  #=> has the value jack
```

I was looking for variable reference like in Perl, but came up nothing in Ruby.

---------- EDIT

I am in the middle of doing the lynda  ruby on rails tutorial, and in the middle of creating a module to adjust positions of items in a table.
unfortunately when I first started I named my tables columns differently
`pages.page_position, subjects.subject_position, sections.section_position`

now the module PositionMover is to be used accross three models, so now
I have a problem since the attributes names are different for each model

so I thought no worry I'll just create a pointer / refference for each model

`:position = :pages_position , :position = :subjects_position , :position = :section_position`

hence the question , if its even possible to do it.

if its not possible , any suggestion what should I do , so the module can 
be used accross three different models , with different attribute names.

sorry I am a newbie.

Comment: What's your use case for this? Knowing it might help us find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Symbols are not like variables, they are actually a object type, like String or Fixnum so you can have a variable that is of type symbol.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
attribute = :first_name
user0.update_attribute(attribute, "jack")
user0.first_name  #=> has the value jack
```

**Update:** If you have a String and need to convert to a symbol, (I'm not sure if you need this for `update_attribute`)

```
foo = "string"
foo.to_sym #=> :string
```

Comment: This is what I had in the end, using the .to_sym method. but will now try using the `attribute = :first_name`

Answer (score 1):

Use the **alias_attribute** . Define into each model like :

**Page model**

alias_attribute :position , :pages_position

**Subject Model**

alias_attribute :position , :subjects_position

**Section Model**

alias_attribute :position , :section_position

And use (Model.position = values) with each model . Hope Its solution of your problem .

Comment: This is another approach that  I just tried, quick question, I tested both using :position and :subject_position, they both work , is this expected ?

Comment: yes because your are creating alias so you can also call it by other name .

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `send` [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) and use symbols or strings to reference the attribute's methods. `send` can be incredibly useful since it enables you to choose the method that you'll be invoking at runtime.

Eg

```
user.first_name = "Jack" # set first_name to Jack
                         # Note: method "first_name=" (a settor) is being used    

attribute = "first_name"
user.send attribute + "=", "Jack" # set first_name to Jack
                                  # The string "first_name=" is coerced into
                                  # a symbol

attribute = :first_name
val = user.send attribute # => returns "Jack"
```

Answer (score 0):

see the definition of `update_attribute` in the `ActiveRecord::Persistence` module on [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L161):

```
def update_attribute(name, value)
  name = name.to_s
  verify_readonly_attribute(name)
  send("#{name}=", value)
  save(:validate => false)
end
```

this leads me to believe you could add the following to your model to achieve that behavior:

```
alias_method :fname_ref= :first_name=
```

I'd be interested to know why you want to do that as @Andrew Marshall asked.